# Symfony database connection to CockroachDB

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, cockroachdb

after several attempts I still don't understand what's happening, I'm trying to connect my database to a CockroachDB database, so I have this in my .env:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://user:password@serveur_address:port/database_name?sslmode=verify-full
```

When I do a migration I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  server requires encryption
> FATAL:  codeParamsRoutingFailed: missing cluster identifier
> HINT:  Ensure that your cluster identifier is uniquely specified using any of the
> following methods:

1. Host name:
   Use a driver that supports server name identification (SNI) with TLS
   connection and the hostname assigned to your cluster
   (e.g. serverless-101.5xj.gcp-us-central1.cockroachlabs.cloud)
2. Options parameter:
   Use "--cluster=" as the options parameter.
   (e.g. options="--cluster=active-roach-42")
3. Database parameter:
   Use "." as the database parameter.
   (e.g. database="active-roach-42.defaultdb")

I've tried several things, nothing works... do you have any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) "I've tried several things, nothing works..." --> What exactly have you tried already? (Please click on "Edit" to edit your question and include the info there). Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when trying to connect to cockroach db from a GCP instance using a Python script. The Python script is working fine in my Windows local machine but it's not working in the GCP instance. I had to pass the database name with the prefix in the hostname.

for example, my hostname is:

```
testdatabase-7785.8nk.cockroachlabs.cloud
```

my database name is:

```
testdatabasename
```

so my database name in the database URL should be:

```
testdatabase-7785.testdatabasename
```

the working database url is:

```
export DATABASE_URL="postgresql://testuser:IJBDbwiabiBDCIbeif@testdatabase-7785.8nk.cockroachlabs.cloud:26257/testdatabase-7785.testdatabasename?sslmode=verify-full"
```

I had to include the testdatabase-7785. as a prefix to the database name. Hope this helps.